# Como permitir somente a criação de objetos válidos no Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

```
class Linha(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, valor):
        if valor >= 0:
            self._x = valor
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
    @y.setter
    def y(self, valor):
        if valor >= 0:
            self._y = valor
```

Eu criei essa classe que basicamente abstrai uma linha, percebam que fiz uso de decoradores setters de forma que não permita a entrada de valor menor que 0.

Mas quando tento criar uma instância de Linha se eu passar um dos parâmetros  como menor que 0 ele mesmo assim faz a criação do objeto mas não cria esse atributo.

Exemplo:

```
linha = Linha(-1, 1)
```

Se eu fizer isso ele ira criar o objeto mas ele não possuirá o atributo x pois o  mesmo não será setado. Se pior ainda se eu passar os dois atributos negativos o objeto será criado mas  não possuirá nenhum atributo.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: como evito a criação de um objeto inválido? Ou seja se for passado um ou mais parâmetros inválidos o objeto não é criado.

Comment: Eu creio que este seja o caso de lançar uma exceção, no lugar de transparentemente ignorar a atribuição do atributo. A propósito, você abstraiu um ponto no primeiro quadrante, não exatamente uma linha. Até dá para a partir dessas informações gerar uma linha, mas neste caso você estaria sendo enganoso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Jefferson comentou na pergunta, você pode lançar uma exceção quando o número definido for inválido, neste caso, menor que zero. A exceção irá desviar o fluxo do programa, delegando a lógica de tratamento do *erro* para uma camada superior, o programa que cria a instância da classe.

```
class Linha(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, valor):
        if valor >= 0:
            self._x = valor
        else:
            raise ValueError("The x value must be a non-negative number")

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, valor):
        if valor >= 0:
            self._y = valor
        else:
            raise ValueError("The y value must be a non-negative number")
```

Outro detalhe que possivelmente seja válido fazer nesta situação, visto que dentro dos métodos você compara o valor com um número inteiro, é garantir que esta comparação seja possível de se fazer garantindo que o valor também seja numérico. Isto é, se eu fizesse `obj.x = 'a'`, daria um erro dizendo que o operador `>=` não suporta uma comparação entre uma string e um inteiro. Essa é uma péssima mensagem de erro para entregar ao seu cliente (quem utiliza a classe). Para contornar isso, você pode converter o valor de entrada para inteiro (ou float), antes de efetuar a comparação:

```
class Linha(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, valor):
        valor_inteiro = int(valor)
        if valor_inteiro >= 0:
            self._x = valor_inteiro
        else:
            raise ValueError("The x value must be a non-negative number")

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, valor):
        valor_inteiro = int(valor)
        if valor_inteiro >= 0:
            self._y = valor_inteiro
        else:
            raise ValueError("The y value must be a non-negative number")
```

Assim, se eu tentar criar a instância `Linha('a', 0)`, a mensagem de erro será:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Que é muito mais clara quanto ao que está errado no código e, inclusive, faz com que o método sempre lance a mesma exceção, `ValueError`, nos dois casos possíveis, o que facilita o tratamento na camada superior.

```
try:
    x = input("Valor de x:")
    y = input("Valor de y:")
    linha = Linha(x, y)
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
```